# $\psi (m)\leq \phi (m)$ or $\psi (m) \geq \phi (m)$ when $\psi (m)\neq 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

(This is different than [If $x^m=e$ has at most $m$ solutions for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$, then $G$ is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50791/if-xm-e-has-at-most-m-solutions-for-any-m-in-mathbbn-then-g-is-cycl))

I was trying to solve this:

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$ for which the number of solutions of $x^m=e$ is at most $m$ for any $m$ dividing $n$. Prove that $G$ must be cyclic. [Hint:Let $\psi (m)$ be the number of elements in $G$ of order $m$. Show that $\psi (m)\leq \phi (m)$, and use $n=\Sigma_{m\mid n}\phi (m) $]

What I have proven is that $\Sigma_{d|n}(ψ(d)−ϕ(d))=0$, then if the statement in the hint holds, ψ(d)=ϕ(d) for every d|n. n divides itself, therefore, $\psi (n)=ϕ(n)≠0$. Therefore G admits a generator, and we'll be done.The problem is to prove the statement in the hint. Yet I have conluded a different seemingly contradictory result, which doesn't help solve the problem at all, since it could be that $ψ(n)=0,ψ(n)−ψ(d)<0$ and $ψ(d)−ϕ(d)>0$ for some $d≠n$. Of course I don't know how to show that $\psi (m)\leq \phi (m)$, and here is how I got this contradiction:

If $\psi (m)\neq 0$, then let $m\neq 1,m\mid n$. Consider an element $a\in G,|a|=m$. Within its cyclic group, there will be $\phi (m)$ elements with order $m$ since any element $a^i$ in it is a generator if and only if $\gcd(m,i)=1$. Therefore $\psi(m) \geq \phi (m)$ since some element out side the cyclic group may have order $m$ too.

If this reasoning is correct, I think it will contradict with the fact in the hint which is $\phi(m) \geq \phi(m)$. The number of solutions is $\Sigma_{d|m}\psi (d)$, which is always greater than $\psi (m)$. So no matter how great $\psi (m)$ is, or how $\psi (m) >\phi (m)$, the number of solution may still be less than $m$. What's going wrong? How to prove the statment in the hint? Help me please. Also I have read through [If $x^m=e$ has at most $m$ solutions for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$, then $G$ is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50791/if-xm-e-has-at-most-m-solutions-for-any-m-in-mathbbn-then-g-is-cycl), but for the accepted answer, it doesn't show how to prove the fact in the hint, and other answers do not use the fact in the hint.

Comment: I'm not sure your question is different from the other one. Both are quantifying over all $m$. If you just use one $m$, say $m = 1$, the statement is no longer true.

Comment: BUt under some condition the statement holds and it contradicts with the fact in hint

Comment: If some element $x$ outside $\langle a \rangle$ has order (dividing) $m$, then within $\langle a, x \rangle \leq G$, you would have $> m$ different solutions of $y^m = e$.

Comment: Why >m solutions?

Comment: Everything in $\langle a \rangle$ and also $x$ would be a solution.

Comment: If within <a> $\phi (m)$ elements  satisfy the equation, and outside<a>, there are $\phi (m)$ elements in <b> satisfy the euqtion, will it be necessarily true that $2\phi (m)>m$?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "necessary." If you assume the assertion in the problem that $x^m = e$ admits $\leq m$ solutions, then it can't be true at all.

Comment: $2\phi (m)$ won't be necessarily greater than m, so there may still not be more than m solutions.

Comment: I think the reason why I didn't figure it out is that I didn't utilize the fact of group G being abelian. But in fact I don't know how to use it either.

Comment: Any element of $\langle a \rangle$ is a solution to $x^m = e$. There are $m$ of them. $\phi(m)$ is the number of elements $x$ of that subgroup such that $m$ *is the smallest number* such that $x^m = e$. There are fewer of those. For example, in the cyclic group of order $m = 4$  generated by some $|a|$, we have $|a| = |a^3| = 4$, whilst $|a^2| = 2$ and $a^4 = e$. Thus there are $\phi(4) = 2$ fourth roots of $e$, but $4$ elements $x$ such that $x^4 = e$.

Comment: That will show that $\psi (m)\geq \phi (m)$

Comment: $\psi(m) = |\{x \in G : m\mbox{ is the least natural number such that }x^m = e\}|$. One always has $\psi(m) = \phi(m)$ for all $m$ in the case of a cyclic group.

Comment: Of course, when it's a cyclic group, these are equal. And to your last comment, Let S be the solution set. you showed that |S|=$\Sigma_{d|m} \psi(d)>\phi(m)$ under some cases. What I have proved is that $\Sigma_{d|n}(\psi(d)-\phi(d))=0$, then if the statement in the hint holds, $\psi(d)=\phi (d)$ for every $d|n$. n divides itself, therefore, $\psi (n)=\phi (n)\neq 0$. Therefore $G$ admits a generator, and we'll be done. The problem is to prove the statement in the hint.

Comment: Yet I have conluded a different seemingly contradictory result, which doesn't help solve the problem at all, since it could be that $\psi (n)=0,\psi(n)-\psi(d)<0$ and $\psi (d)- \phi (d)>0$ for some $d\neq n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d\mid n$ and suppose that $g\in G$ has order $d$.  Then
$$1,g,g^2,\ldots,g^{d-1}$$
are all different, and are solutions of the equation $x^d=e$ in $G$.  We have exhibited $d$ solutions of the equation, and so by assumption there are no further solutions.  Moreover, not all the powers $g^k$ have order $d$, as some will have smaller order.  In fact, $g^k$ has order $d$ if and only if $k$ is relatively prime to $d$, and so the number of elements of order $d$ is $\phi(d)$, and we have $\psi(d)=\phi(d)$.  This argument rests on the assumption that there is some element of order $d$; but if there is not then $\psi(d)=0$, and certainly in either case we have $\psi(d)\le\phi(d)$.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer, but it uses more knowledge than I think we want to. In particular, it comes close to using the structure theorem for finite abelian groups.

I claim that for any finite abelian group $G$ of order $n$ and any $m|n$, there is a subgroup $H \leq G$ of order $m$. If you can accept this, I can provide a proof. I don't like that I have to assume this. Write $\psi_H(d)$ for the number of elements of $H$ of order exactly $d$.

The assumption on $G$ can be rephrased as $m \geq \sum_{d|m} \psi(m)$; an element $x$ has $x^m = e$ just if its exact order divides $m$.

Given an $H \leq G$ of order $m$, every element is of order dividing $m$, so one has $$\sum_{d|m} \psi_H(d) = m = \sum_{d|m} \phi(d).$$ Since $\psi(d) = \psi_G(d) \geq \psi_H(d)$, one has for all $m|n$ that $$\sum_{d|m} \psi_G(d) \geq \sum_{d|m} \phi(d).$$

Also, if there is any element of order $m$, then there are at least $\phi(m)$ elements of order $m$, so $|T_m| = \psi(m) \geq \phi(m)$ for all $m|n$ such that $T_m \neq \emptyset$.

Note that $A_1 = \{e\}$, and $\psi(1) = \phi(1) = 1$.

Let $m | n$. Inductively assume that for all $d$ properly dividing $m$, we have $\psi(d) = \phi(d)$.

By assumption, $$\sum_{d|m} \phi(d) = m \geq \sum_{d|m} \psi(d).$$ 
Separating out the terms $\phi(m)$ and $\psi(m)$, one gets
$$\phi(m) + \sum_{d|m\ \&\ d \neq m} \phi(d) \geq \psi(m) + \sum_{d|m\ \&\ d \neq m} \psi(d).
$$
By the inductive assumption, the sums are equal, so $\phi(m) \geq \psi(m)$. But if $\psi(m)$ were 0, since for all $d|m$ we have $\phi(m) = \psi(m)$, we couldn't have $\sum_{d|m} \psi(d) \geq \sum_{d|m} \phi(d)$, so $\psi(m) \neq 0$ and hence $\psi(m) = \phi(m)$, concluding the induction.

Obviously this is horrible, but I don't see another way to complete the induction. We know that the entire sums $\sum_{d|n} \phi(d)$ and $\sum_{d|n} \psi(d)$ are equal (both must equal $n$), but I don't see how to use this as an inductive step without leveraging some of the structure theory of abelian groups or $p$-Sylow groups.

Comment: I have already found a proof that is simpler than yours. But I still accepted your answer rather than David's, because I can see you did a lot of work on this problem, and I'm very grateful for your help, so thanks. Moreover a bounty will encourage you to continue to work hard like this

Comment: I worked *too* hard on this answer, and missed that it was in fact very simple. That isn't something you should want to encourage. David's answer is better than mine in all conceivable ways, and I would accept it, if I were you.