# $x^n=a$ has at most $n$ roots.

Tags: group-theory

I want to prove that, in a cyclic group $G$, that there are at most $n$ roots to $x^n=a$ where $a \in G$. I know this is true in the reals but why is it true for groups?

Comment: I am not familiar with group theory, but this looks related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50791/if-xm-e-has-at-most-m-solutions-for-any-m-in-mathbbn-then-g-is-cycl.

Comment: Do you assume that it's a cyclic group?

Comment: @Wesley if necessary, yes.

Comment: Looks like it is necessary.

Comment: Oh obviously it isn't true for all groups

Comment: Then the matter becomes whether it suffices to let $G$ be cyclic.

Comment: Do we need to specify a certain order for the group?

Comment: Just a thought, what if you could prove that if there are more than $n$ roots, $G$ is not cyclic?

Comment: "Just a thought, what if you could prove that if there are more than n roots, G is not cyclic?"  That wouldn't be enough.  It's still hypothetically possible that G is cycle and has n or few roots.  $A \to B \iff \lnot B\to \lnot A$ but $\lnot A \to \lnot B \not \implies A \to B$.

Comment: The statement "cyclic $\implies$ at most $n$ roots" would have as its contrapositive "more than $n$ roots $\implies$ not cyclic". As I suggested, or is something off in my reasoning here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z_m}$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$ are all the cyclic groups up to isomorphism, so it is enough to check for them. I think for $\mathbb{Z}$ your statement is pretty much obvious. So you just have to check for $\mathbb{Z_m}$. So let $n\in\mathbb{N},a\in\mathbb{Z_m}$ when $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Now your equation looks like $nx\equiv a$(mod $m$). Can it have more than $n$ solutions?

Comment: How did $x^n$ become $nx$?

Comment: Becuase in the specific group $\mathbb{Z_m}$ the operation is addition. OP wrote $x^n$ because in a general group we usually write the operation as multiplication.

Comment: @Mark I must be missing something obvious but why does this cannot have more than $n$ solutions?

Comment: @Sorfosh, this is a property of linear congruences. The number of solutions to the congruence $nx\equiv a$(mod $m$) is at most $\gcd(n,m)$ which of course can't be more than $n$. Of course the "solutions" here are congruence classes mod $m$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.