# Proof by contradiction using properties of normal subgroup: A group is cyclic if $x^m=e$ has at most $m$ solutions.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, cyclic-groups

**Statement**:

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Show that if for each positive integer $m$ the number of solutions $x$ of the equation $x^n=e$ in $G$ is at most $n$, then $G$ is cyclic.

There are various proofs available as answers to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50791/955582).

Inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/875147/955582) (which I did not find convincing), I am attempting to write a proof on my own (**point out errors or fallacies, if any**).

---

### **My attempt**:

**Define**: $\mathcal S(n) := \{ g\in G \ | \ g^n=e\}$

**Given**: $G$ is finite and $ |\mathcal S(n)|\leq n$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z^+$.

**Assumption**: Suppose, if possible, $G$ be non-cyclic.

$G$ is finite $\implies$ G has at least one element (say, $x$) of maximal order $M$.
$M=\max\{\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}\ord(g) \ | \ g\in G\}\tag*{}$
$G$ being non-cyclic, $M\neq |G|$, for otherwise, $x$ will generate $G$.

$G$ is non-cyclic $\implies$ $G\setminus \langle x \rangle$ is non-empty, so it has at least one element (say, $y$) of minmal order $m$.
$m=\min\{\ord(g) \ | \ g\in G\setminus \langle x \rangle \}\tag*{}$

**Claim 1**: $\mathcal S(M) =\langle x\rangle$ and $\mathcal S(m) =\langle y\rangle$

This can be proven by a counting argument.
All elements of $\langle x\rangle$ satisfy the equation $g^M=e$ so, $\langle x\rangle\subseteq \mathcal S(M)$. Now, use that fact that $|\langle x\rangle|= \ord(x)=M$ and that $|\mathcal S(M)|\leq M$.

**Claim 2**: $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle y \rangle$ are normal in $G$.
For all $g\in G$ and $h\in \langle x\rangle $, $(ghg^{-1})^M=gh^Mg^{-1}=e\implies ghg^{-1}\in \mathcal S(M)=\langle x\rangle\tag*{}$ Repeat the same argument for $\langle y\rangle$.

**Lemma**: If $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of any group $G$ such that $H\cap K=\{e\}$ then the elements of $H$ and $K$ commute with each other.

For all $h\in H$ and $k\in K$,
$hkh^{-1}{k^{-1}}=\underbrace{(hkh^{-1})}_{\in K}k^{-1}=h\underbrace{(khk^{-1})^{-1}}_{\in H}\tag*{}$ By normality and closure, $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H\cap K$ so,  $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}=e$.

Now  with these claims and lemmas at hand, we are equipped to proceed. There are three possible cases:

**Case 1**: $\DeclareMathOperator{\gcd}{gcd}\gcd(M,m)=1$.

This would mean that $S(M)\cap S(m)=\{e\}$ and hence, $\langle x\rangle \cap \langle y\rangle=\{e\}$.

Now, claim 2 followed by the lemma, we know that $xy=yx$.

$\therefore$ $\ord(xy)=\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}\lcm(M,m)=Mm\leq M$
( $\because$ $M$ is the maximal order of $G$) $\iff m=1$.

Now, $\ord(y)=1\implies y=e \in \langle x\rangle$. This is a contradiction because $y$ was chosen such that $y\in G\setminus \langle x\rangle$.

We can conclude that in this case, $G\setminus \langle x\rangle$ is empty, so $G=\langle x\rangle$ as required.

**Case 2**: $1<\gcd(M,m)<m$

Suppose $\text{gcd}(M,m)=d$ for some $1<d<m$.

$\quad$ **Claim 2.1**: $y^d\not \in \langle x\rangle$.

$\ord(y^d)=m/d$. However, as a consequence of Lagrange's theorem, $\langle x\rangle $ cannot not have any element of this order because $m/d$ does not divide $M$.

In fact, $\gcd(M, m/d)=1$ because we have removed the highest possible common factor from $m$.

By the requirement that $m$ is the minimal order in $G\setminus \langle x\rangle$:

$m=\min\left(m, \ord(y^d) \right)\implies m\leq \frac{m}d \implies d=1$ which is the case 1.

**Case 3**: $\gcd(M,m)=m$ i.e., $m$ divides $M$.

$\ord(y)=m, \ m\ | \ M \implies y^M=e \implies y\in\mathcal S(M)=\langle x\rangle\tag*{}$
This is again a contradiction because of choice of $y\in G\setminus \langle x\rangle$.

This completes the proof. $\blacksquare$

---

### **What I did not find convincing in the linked answer**:

In the linked answer, the case 2 was $d=\gcd(m,M)>1$ and the element $y^{m/d}$ was picked from $\langle y\rangle$ which is of order $d$. Then it was argued that $m$ is the minimal order so, $d\leq m$ and hence, $d=m$.

But $m$ is the minimal order of elements of $G\setminus \langle 
x\rangle$. **How are we guaranteed that $y^{m/d}\not \in \langle x\rangle$?**

I think it is possible that $y^{m/d}\in \langle x\rangle$ so it can have an order less than $m$. **Am I missing out on something or is this really a flaw in the linked proof**?

---

**Update**: Unfortunately, I found a mistake...The argument for claim 2.1 is false. $m/d$ may divide $M$ and it's not necessary that $\text{gcd}(m/d, M)=1$. For instance, $\text{gcd}(4,6)=2$ but $4/2$ does divide $6$.  So there needs to be some way to rewrite the proof for case 2.

Comment: Do you want an explanation of the proof linked to (in which case use the [tag:proof-explanation] tag and copy & paste the answer here to make it self-contained) or do you want a solution verification (in which case, from the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough"*)?

Comment: @Shaun I think I have sufficiently understood the proof in the linked answer. I believe there is a mistake in it which is why I said I didn't find it convincing and have pointed the mistake in my post. I want to know if that's really a mistake or I am missing out on something? My version of the proof is almost same as the linked answer till the **case 1**.  I also want to be sure that it doesn't have any flaw, so I added the "proof-verification" tag which somehow became "solution-verification"...

Comment: Proof looks good to me.

Comment: They're logged as synonyms.

Comment: You need to follow the advice of the tax wiki, as I quoted. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/synonyms

Comment: @Shaun I have read the wikis of both proof-verification and proo-explanation. Edited and have highlighted in bold what I want to know exactly.

Comment: @Steve D Unfortunately, I found a mistake...The argument for claim 2.1 is false. $m/d$ may divide $M$. For e.g. $\text{gcd}(4,6)=2$ but $4/2$ divides $6$.  So there needs to be some way to rewrite the proof for case 2.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Sorry, I don't see a way to fix this without essentially giving a new proof of your title statement. Not sure if that's worth it or not, but here it is anyway: note that $\langle y^{m/d}\rangle=\langle x^{M/d}\rangle$, so $S(d)$ is central in $\langle x,y\rangle$. Your case 1 shows $\langle x,y\rangle/S(d)$ is cyclic, and thus $\langle x,y\rangle$ has a central cyclic quotient: that means it's Abelian. The rest is easy.

Comment: I guess one way to avoid the Abelian-ness in my comment above is to note that once you show the quotient is cyclic , that implies an element in $G$ with order divisible by $Mm/d$. Since $m>d$ that's a contradiction.

Comment: I understand that $S(d)$ is a subgroup of the centre of $\langle x,y\rangle$ and I know that it is normal. But I didn't understand how did you prove that the quotient group $\langle x,y\rangle/S(d)$ is cyclic? I understand the result that follows (abelianness).

Comment: @Nothingspecial: in the quotient, the groups $\langle\overline{x}\rangle$ and $\langle\overline{y}\rangle$ have orders $M/d$ and $m/d$ respectively, and these are relatively prime. So your Lemma shows $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$ commute. In particular, $\overline{xy}$ generates the quotient.

Comment: @SteveD Sorry for this late reply, I was bit busy with college tests... Check the answer I have posted with my understanding of your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Steve D](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/265452/steve-d)'s comments, I will rewrite the case-2 correctly.

**Case 2:** $1<\DeclareMathOperator{\gcd}{gcd}\underbrace{\gcd(M,m)}_{=d}<m$

The elements $x^{M/d}$ and $y^{m/d}$ both have an order of $d$ and hence, it is necessary that $\mathcal S(d)=\langle x^{M/d}\rangle = \langle y^{m/d}\rangle\tag*{}$ in order to maintain the constraint that $|\mathcal S(d)|\leq d$.

$\quad$ **Claim 2.1**: $x$ and $y$ commute with every element of $\mathcal S(d)$.

Consider the group $G'=\langle x, y\rangle$ which is a subgroup of $G$.

$\quad$ **Claim 2.2:** $\mathcal S(d)$ is a subgroup of the centre of $G'$ i.e., $\mathbf Z(G')$.

Consider the quotient group $G'/\mathcal S(d)$ which contains the cosets $\overline x= x\cdot \mathcal S(d)$ and $\overline y = y\cdot\mathcal S(d)$.

Consider the subgroups of $G'/\mathcal S(d)$ generated by the cosets $\overline x$ and $\overline y$.

$\langle \overline x\rangle = \{x^i\cdot\mathcal S(d) \ | \ i=1,2,\ldots, M/d\}\tag*{}$

$\langle \overline y\rangle = \{y^i\cdot\mathcal S(d) \ | \ i=1,2,\ldots, m/d\}\tag*{}$

$\quad$ **Claim 2.3:** These two subgroups are normal in $G'/\mathcal S(d)$ and their intersection is singleton identity i.e., $\{\mathcal S(d)\}$.

Using the lemma in my original post, we are assured that $\overline x$ and $\overline y$ commute over coset multiplication.

$\quad$ **Claim 2.4:** Every coset of $G'/\mathcal S(d)$ is of the form $(\overline x)^i (\overline y)^j$ which can be re-written as $(\overline x\overline y)^k$ because $\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}\ord(\overline x)$ and $\ord(\overline y)$ are co-prime.

Hence, $G'/\mathcal S(d) =\langle \overline x\overline y\rangle$

$\quad$ **Claim 2.5:** $x$ and $y$ commute in $G'$.

Hence, $\ord(xy)=\text{lcm}(M,m)=\frac{Mm}{d}$.

By definition of maximal order, we need that $\frac{Mm}{d}\leq M$ i.e., $m\leq d$ which is a contradiction.